# Listbox with multi selection Checklist is not appearing

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#<%=ddEVNT1.ClientID %>').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
</script>
```

**Code:**

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddEVNT1" runat="server" Width="90%" Style="font-family: Calibri; 
                                font-size: 15px;" Visible="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="--Select Event--" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="50 m flat race for Boys" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Musical Chair" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Tug-of-war" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Penalty Shoot out" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Go as you like" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Multiselect JavaScript and CSS have been called.

Comment: How is ddEVNT1 populated?

Comment: Now there will be some default value. But after that I will pull data from sql

Comment: Can you show how you populate ddEVNT1? You assume it was successfully populated but it does not appear, which is not necessarily accurate.

Comment: Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim qry As String = "Select EP_PAR_VALUE from [SANDBOX].[dbo].[T_EVENT_PARAM] where EP_PAR_TYPE = 'FD' and EP_PAR_DESC='M' and EP_PAR_REM > '05' and EP_MIN_AGE < '05'"
        Using con As New SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING)
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(qry, con)
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

Comment: Try
                If (con.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then
                    con.Open()
                End If
                da.Fill(dt)

            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw
            End Try
            con.Close()
        End Using
        ddEVNT1.DataSource = dt
        ddEVNT1.DataTextField = "EP_PAR_VALUE"
        ddEVNT1.DataValueField = "EP_PAR_VALUE"
        ddEVNT1.DataBind()

Comment: Kindly suggest if there will be any change in the code and thanks a lot for your reply

Comment: How many items are populated into ddEVNT1? Can you check that? Is it empty?

Comment: Right now Im showing some static values as mentioned above.

Comment: 2 values are coming from that sql query. Checked it in SQL developer

Comment: Do you have anything related to ddEVNT1 in your generated HTML?

Comment: No i want to bring the data in ddevent1. And show it with check box list

Comment: Improved formatting for better reading.